# android google maps sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

how i can change `addMarker` with much marker from sqlite database? i'm using pre-database with assets folder. /assets

my concept just wanna take marker from sqlite reffering by name. and i have many many name with `LatLong` of anyone. any body help me please?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng malang = new LatLng(-7.963535, 112.640756);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(malang, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("SMP Negeri 20")
            .snippet("Jl. RT Suryo 38")
            .position(malang));
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
```

that's simple code from

> Google Maps Developers

Answer (score 0):

get data from database and assign it into arrays like.

```
LatLon[] latlon;// assign latitude and longitude from database
String[] names; //assign names from database;
for(int i=0; i< getDataFromDataBase.length; i++)
{
    latlon[i] = getDataFromDataBase.getlatlon(i);
    names[i] = getDataFromDataBase.getnames(i)
}
```

after this change your

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("SMP Negeri 20")
            .snippet("Jl. RT Suryo 38")
            .position(malang));
```

to this code

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < latlon.length() ; i++ ) 
{
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(names[i])
            .position(latlon[i]));
}
```

Comment: thank's for comment, but am i shouldn't add some code like "order by name" or others?? @Nitin

Comment: Yeah definitely you can add that into your sql query.

Comment: that is a cursor from database which helps you to fetch data from sql.

Comment: your email please? @Nitin